# How to import style with webpack?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to use react-image-gallery package, I followed the documentation, but I don't get the css into my app and I don't know why.
In the docs it says to import the css with webpack like this :

SCSS

```
@import "~react-image-gallery/styles/scss/image-gallery.scss";
```

CSS

```
@import "~react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";
```

but nothing happens when I put this into my js or css files. Any idea how this should be done ?

Comment: can you try to use it in a simple way?
import "react-image-gallery/styles/css/image-gallery.css";

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work either...

Comment: which version of react, are you using?